# how to get the content from URL using c# webbrower1

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, webbrowser-control

how to get portion of website, in webbrowser1 any idea how do this please see below image, i want only flight grid..  I have below code,

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

                this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.manchesterairport.co.uk/flight-information/");
 }
```

**i want show only selected div(content), to show web broswer1 . not full page,**

how do this, i have URL : http://www.manchesterairport.co.uk/flight-information/

[image]

Comment: Did they provide any API?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Where are you stuck? You can get elements by tag or id from the webbrowser control, or really you should get the full HTML and parse it using something like Html Agility Pack.

Comment: i dont have any API.. i want show this page in my C# webbrowser1, but not full page, i want only show grid

Comment: Oh, now you've edited your question it's a little different. This would be very difficult as Patrick's answer suggests. Even if you could parse the HTML it would be missing stylesheets/javascript and anything else that made the table look nice and work correctly.

Comment: yes  i am new in development , that's why i ask this type of question ... ;( i think its not possible to get only grid ;(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746719/how-to-winform-texboxt-text-transfer-value-web-page-textbox

Answer (score 0):

Showing only the grid will be really hard. Perhaps you could load the content and inject your own javascript using your C# browser into the page.

In your script you can manipulate the view of the page remove or extract DOM-Elements to get only the part of the page you want to display. This solution has one big problem. If the manchesterairpot.com Layout changes you will always have to rewrite your code.

Don't they provide an API? Otherwise i would suggest to use: https://developer.flightstats.com/api-docs/flightstatus/v2/airport This API should provide you the information you need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746719/how-to-winform-texboxt-text-transfer-value-web-page-textbox