# how to winform texboxt Text transfer value web page textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, textbox, webbrowser-control

I have `textbox1`, I want to transfer `textbox1.Text` into `webbrowser1` web page textbox, how to do this?

I have below code, but webpage text box selected index change event not fired. How to do this?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    HtmlElement HTMLControl2 = doc.GetElementById("flightno-filter");
    //HTMLControl.Style = "'display: none;'";
    if (HTMLControl2 != null)
    {
        // HTMLControl2.Style = "display: none";
        HTMLControl2.InnerText = textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Please see below image

[image]

Comment: private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
            HtmlElement HTMLControl2 = doc.GetElementById("flightno-filter");
            //HTMLControl.Style = "'display: none;'";
            if (HTMLControl2 != null)
            {
                // HTMLControl2.Style = "display: none";
                HTMLControl2.InnerText = textBox1.Text;
            }

          
        } but webbrowser seleted indexchange event not fired

Comment: Add the code in you post by editing it as you can see it is unreadable in comments section.

Comment: which event is not fired? add that code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to input text to webpage then make make the webbrowser raise the change/input event of the input box? You have to invoke "onChange" event or some other event.

Bellow I make WebBrowser raise keydown event, use SendKey:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    HtmlElement HTMLControl2 = doc.GetElementById("flightno-filter");
    //HTMLControl.Style = "'display: none;'";
    if (HTMLControl2 != null)
    {
        // HTMLControl2.Style = "display: none";
        HTMLControl2.InnerText = textBox1.Text;

        HTMLControl2.Focus();              // Set focus to input box
        SendKeys.SendWait("{Right}");      // Send "Right" key
        textBox1.Focus();                  // Give focus back for one of WinForms control

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) its works for me.. thanks your great,

Comment: and how to fire onclick event  ?

Comment: That is other question, because you don't ask it in your above question. Create new question and describe which site (URL) you are working, which element you are trying to click, what you tried (describe need to be detail, otherwise people will dock point from you).

Comment: Right. If you ask new one and comment here to inform me, I can help you :)

Comment: http://www.heathrow.com/arrivals  I HAVE this site  and want also same functionality ;( how do this , this webpage textbox file onclick event @Sakura

Comment: Could you please post it as a new question? I'll happily answer you. Now I don't know what element you want to click. Describe which textbox/button you want to click (textbox don't have onclick event), mark it with color like this question, If possible, post the code what you have tried, say what you want (be detail, if not people will downvote you).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768309/how-to-webpage-texboxt-onclick-event-fire-from-winformtextbox