# how to webpage textbox onclick event fire from winform textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have below code,when i search from my winform textbox and click search button but webpage text box onclick event not fired. How to do this? here is :http://www.heathrow.com/arrivals when i click search button page still same position, show in 2nd number image. internet explorer 11 i have installed

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
            HtmlElement HTMLControl2 = doc.GetElementById("searchInput");

            if (HTMLControl2 != null)
            {
                // HTMLControl2.Style = "display: none";
                HTMLControl2.InnerText = textBox1.Text;

                HTMLControl2.Focus();

                SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                textBox1.Focus();

            }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not clear what you ask. Even when I type to that box directly string `aa` then press `Enter`, nothing happen. So what behavior you expect on that page?

Comment: When you type enough 6 character, that site will auto process that text, if not, it will ignore. Same with the browser.

Comment: NO search winform search button not working this site ;(

Comment: Wait for page load finish, type the text `aa6414` and click search button you will see the page process your query.

Comment: no page still same position only textbox fill;(

Comment: It's hard to help you because you want to keep secret what exactly behavior you want. I only can tell that in my app, when use finish type `aa6414` (NOTE: 6 CHARS AND CONTAINS ONE OF FLIGHT NUMBER) the page redirect to other page

Comment: what browser r u using ? because page still same position when i click search

Comment: The built-in WebBrowser control.

Comment: I HAVE INSTALLED Internet explorer 11 ..;(

Comment: That does not matter, for compatibility Winforms will use IE7 to brow web page, unless the app change specific settings. So, your WebBrowser and mine both are IE7 (My Win8.1 IE browser is IE 11 by default)

Comment: please share your code.. mr.addikhan@gmail.com ... please

Comment: I copy your code with out a character change. If you need, I can post as a answer bellow.

Comment: ok please show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

Form1.cs:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    HtmlElement HTMLControl2 = doc.GetElementById("searchInput");

    if (HTMLControl2 != null)
    {
        // HTMLControl2.Style = "display: none";
        HTMLControl2.InnerText = textBox1.Text;

        HTMLControl2.Focus();

        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
        textBox1.Focus();

    }
}
```

Anything else is default.

Comment: its same as my app ;(

Comment: Yes, as I said. For one more test, when page load finished, you copy one flight number and paste it to your winforms textbox then click search to see if anything different.

Comment: this code help me ;)
                 SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
               textBox1.Focus();
               HTMLControl2.Focus();
               HTMLControl2.InnerText = textBox1.Text;
              SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
              textBox1.Focus();
              HTMLControl2.Focus();

Answer (score 0):

```
 HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    HtmlElement HTMLControl2 = doc.GetElementById("searchInput");

    if (HTMLControl2 != null)
    {
        // HTMLControl2.Style = "display: none";
        HTMLControl2.InnerText = textBox1.Text;
                 SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
                textBox1.Focus();
               HTMLControl2.Focus();
                HTMLControl2.InnerText = textBox1.Text;
              SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
               textBox1.Focus();
              HTMLControl2.Focus();
}
```